# Can I opt to be not middle relay?

Tags: exit-relays, guard-node, middle

I know that in a Tor circuit, there are typically 3 relays: Guard, Middle, and Exit. If I want to run a Tor relay, can I configure it so that I can only serve as Exit node, or Guard node, but not Middle node?

Answer (score 3):

No, and it will never be implemented: it would break the whole relay idea of Tor. Every relay - *regardless of it's further roles* - is a "regular node", i.e. the middle one. If it's allowed to go outside - then it *also/additionally* receives an Exit flag. If it's stable and not flapping - it receives a Stable flag, if it's stable-flagged and has a decent bandwidth and reacability - it receives a Guard flag. That's how it works! Every node is *evaluated* - and to be able actually evaluated - it must be present in network, *actually* do some work - and *basing on the results and metrics of the working process* it's *additionally* flagged.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, no. If I remember correctly, exit relays are hard-coded to be used *only* as exits, and Tor will prefer to *not* use guard relays for a middle node.

Comment: As the real life stats of my relay shows the truth: as soon as middle point relay with properly open DirPort and ORPort receives Guard flag - nothing actually changes in it's work...

Comment: That's strange: my relay is sometimes guard and sometimes not, and whenever it's guard, its "middle probability" drops by about the same amount as its "guard probability"  is increased